# When should I put as before an adjective?

Tags: prepositions

I’ve been hearing people say “something is not as adj” lately. For example: Face ID is not as safe. This page is not as used.
I wonder if it means that thing is not as safe/used as other things?

Thank you.

Comment: *This page is not as used* isn't really idiomatic. We'd normally say *This page is **not used as much***. I think this represents a general principle for past participles used adjectivally. There are probably specific exceptions (or specific *classes* of exceptions), but offhand I can't think of any.

Answer (score 1):

This is a truncated form of the "as...as..." construction for making comparative sentences.

You can say "Face ID is not as safe as password ID" (for example).  It means "Password ID is safer than Face ID".

You might truncate the expression if there is clear context that allows the listener to fill in the gap:

> Password ID is slow compared to face ID, but face ID is not as safe.

In that example the fact comparison to "Password ID" is clear from the context.  The context might not always be so obvious.  Here's another example:

> My favourite restaurant has been going downhill. The food just isn't as good.  (implying  "as it used to be")